# Returning a value and then assigning it - possible race condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I had code like so - lets simplify it.

```
someObj.newVal = returnSomVal();

function returnSomVal(){
    return grabproperVal();
}

function grabproperVal(){
    var someVal;
    //some js figuring to get proper value for somVal;
    return someVal
    someObj.newVal = setSomeCookie(someObj.newVal,'cookiename');
}
```

Could there exist a race condition in which this happens:

```
someObj.newVal = setSomeCookie(someObj.newVal,'cookiename');
```

before this assignment happens:

```
someObj.newVal = returnSomVal();
```

I am "sometimes" missing out on the var and I don't know if it is my testing methodology or perhaps there "is" a race condition happening. Just trying to narrow things down.

Comment: Why do you expect code after a `return` statement to *ever* execute?

Comment: I think (I hope!) he mistyped (this word exists?)

Comment: **@james emanon** when you `return` the function ends, so nothing will be run after that.

Comment: hmm. I hear what you are saying, but that is impossible because my cookies IS being set. How could that happen "if" the return prohibits the next bit from firing off?

Answer (score 0):

You need to know how these functions behave. The behavior that you are saying seems to be fired because one (or both) of your function(s) is/are asynchronous. You will need to use a callback in the function that must be executed first. When it finishes its asynchronous task, then you execute the second one.